# Rubygems not resolving versions with compound constraints correctly?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, dependencies, nexus

I have tried to install one of our internal gems recently on a non-development setup from our private gemserver (Sonatype Nexus) and received this error when running `gem install db-scripts`:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::DependencyResolutionError)
    conflicting dependencies utilityconfig (>= 0.2.12, ~> 0.2) and utilityconfig (~> 0.2)
  Activated utilityconfig-0.2.0
  which does not match conflicting dependency (>= 0.2.12, ~> 0.2)

  Conflicting dependency chains:
    db-scripts (>= 0), 0.14.1 activated, depends on
    quack (>= 1.6.11, ~> 1.6), 1.6.11 activated, depends on
    utilityconfig (~> 0.2), 0.2.0 activated

  versus:
    db-scripts (>= 0), 0.14.1 activated, depends on
    opower-command (>= 1.3.3, ~> 1.3), 1.3.3 activated, depends on
    utilityconfig (>= 0.2.12, ~> 0.2)

  Gems matching utilityconfig (>= 0.2.12, ~> 0.2):
    utilityconfig-0.2.12
```

I don't understand why a version constraint of simply `'~> 0.2'` on `utilityconfig` in the `quack` gem should conflict with the constraint of `'~> 0.2', '>= 0.2.12'` in `opower-command` in the `db-scripts` gem.

My understanding is that `'~> 0.2'` by itself should allow for versions `0.2...1.0` (exclusive of 1.0, thus the `...` range ;] ), so why should the additional constraint of `'>= 0.2.12'` be in conflict with that?

I also don't understand why it's activating `utilityconfig` version 0.2.0 from the `quack` dependency when 0.2.12 is available on our internal gemserver. Similarly, I actually have a version 1.11.5 of `quack` on the gemserver, so I don't understand why it's activating 1.6.11 (an older version) for that.

Doing a straight `gem install quack` results in version 1.11.5 getting installed, so it's capable of finding the latest release. The `utilityconfig` dependency that gets installed in this case is also 0.2.12, which I would expect to be getting based on the `'~> 0.2'` constraint (0.2.12 is the latest version we have of `utilityconfig`).

Am I just not understanding the dependency definitions correctly or is there something weird going on with my Ruby/rubygems/nexus combination?

I'm using Rubygems 2.4.4 on Ruby 1.9.3-p550 managed by RVM 1.26.0.

Note that I'm using zsh so the `which` commands below actually show the function code from rvm, but I didn't think that would be useful so I ran those in bash.

```
ruby --version; which ruby
ruby 1.9.3p550 (2014-10-27 revision 48165) [x86_64-darwin13.4.0]
/Users/carsten.dreesbach/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p550/bin/ruby

gem --version; which gem
2.4.4
/Users/carsten.dreesbach/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p550/bin/gem

rvm --version; which rvm
rvm 1.26.0 (latest) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
/Users/carsten.dreesbach/.rvm/bin/rvm

echo $GEM_HOME
/Users/carsten.dreesbach/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p550

echo $GEM_PATH
/Users/carsten.dreesbach/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p550:/Users/carsten.dreesbach/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p550@global
```

Comment: Does the `0.2.0 activated` in the log mean, that version 0.2.0 is loaded before the restriction `>= 0.2.12,` is known?

Comment: I guess so, but I don't really know. Shouldn't rubygems try to figure out all possible dependencies before locking things down?